# How to apply custom directive to p-column?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have a primeng datatable in which I want to apply directive to columns.How can I do so?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Do you have anything for us to help you ? Some code ? A template ?